# .test() method in javascript is not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

In this code, the variable value of "ans" is always false whether I have entered value according to pattern or not. I cannot understand the reason.

```js
if (document.getElementById("name") != null)
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
alert("name");
var patt = /[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/;
var ans = patt.test(name);
alert("ans: " + ans);
```

```html
<form>
  name:
  <input type="text" id="name" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="validate();">
</form>
```

Comment: you should create a function instead putting JS in head.

Comment: Ok. Sorry It was my silly mistake....

Answer (score 1):

You used function named `validate` in the submit button event, but did not define it. After defining the `validate` function, everything works fine.

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("name") != null)
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert(name);
  var patt = /[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/;
  var ans = patt.test(name);
  alert("ans: " + ans);
}
```

```html
<form>
  name:
  <input type="text" id="name" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="validate();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form>
    name:
  <input type="text" id="name" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="validate();">
</form>

<script>
function validate(){
if (document.getElementById("name") != null)
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
alert(name);
var patt = /[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/;
var ans = patt.test(name);
alert("ans: " + ans);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move all your code into a defined function `validate()`

```
function validate(){
if (document.getElementById("name") != null)
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
alert("name");
var patt = /[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/;
var ans = patt.test(name);
alert("ans: " + ans);
}
```